# Facing an error while sending file chunks through C++ tcp socket on Windows

Tags: c++, file, sockets, tcp, winsock2

I am working on a project which should read file as binary chunk and send it to a client.

Server Side code:

```
FILE *src = fopen("Video.mp4","rb"); // size of the video is 158 MB

int buffer = (1024*8); //chunk size of 8kb

char filebyte[buffer];

 while(!feof(src)){
    
    filebyte[0]=0; // Clearing the byte array to avoid overlapping
    
    fread(filebyte,buffer,1,src);
        
    send(acpt,filebyte,buffer,0);
   
   filebyte[0]=0; // Clearing the byte array to avoid overlapping
   
   }

fclose(src);
```

Client side Code

```
FILE *target = fopen("ReceivedVideo","wb");
int buffer = (1024*8) ; // chunk size of 8kb
char fileByte[buffer];
int stat;

while(1){
    
    fileByte[0]=0; // Clearing the byte array to avoid overlapping
    
    stat = recv(soc,fileByte,buffer,0);
    
    fwrite(fileByte,buffer,1,target);
    
    fileByte[0]=0; // Clearing the byte array to avoid overlapping
    
    if(stat<0){
        break;
    }
   
   }

fclose(target);
```

But whenever I send any video or any other file, the file output size of client side is always bigger than the original file which was actually sent by the sender.

I sent a video of 158 MB. When the transfer completes, the size of the generated file on the client side is 160 MB and whenever I try to open the received video at client directory, the video player throws an error.

Then I tried sending a small .exe file of 46KB. Had to face same fate again. The .exe generated at client side consumes more bytes and when opened, throws an error.

At last I sent a JPEG image file of 16kb. At the client side, the photo consumed 19kb storage and when compared to the original image, I can clearly see some pixel misplacement or blurry or something like that in the received picture but at least, the image viewer didn't throw an error this time.

The problem I found is, though I clear the chunk storage in server and client side like this

```
filebyte[0]=0; // On server side
fileByte[0]=0; // On client side
```

Still the bytes received at server or client side (I don't really know which side is causing the problem but bit overlapping is the problem -according to me ) gets somehow overlapped and corrupts the file and makes its size bigger.

I am putting full server and client code below.

Full Server Side Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>

#define port 8080



int main(){
    
    int buffer = (1024)*8;
    WSADATA ws;

    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&ws);

    SOCKET soc,acpt;

    sockaddr_in config;

    config.sin_family = AF_INET;
    config.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("0.0.0.0");
    config.sin_port = htons(port);

    /*char* msg = new char[buffer];
    strcpy(msg,"Hello from Server"); */
    
    soc = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
    
    

    bind(soc,(sockaddr*)&config,sizeof(config));

    listen(soc,1);

    acpt = accept(soc,0,0);

   FILE *src;
   
  char filename[100]="Video.mp4";
  
  char filebyte[buffer];
   
   src = fopen(filename,"rb");
   
  
   
   while(!feof(src)){
    
    filebyte[0]=0;
    
    fread(filebyte,buffer,1,src);
        
    send(acpt,filebyte,buffer,0);
   
   filebyte[0]=0;
   
   }
   
   
   
   fclose(src);
   

    std::cout << "Press Enter to exit" <<std::endl;    

//getchar();
return 0;
    
}
```

Full Client Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>


#define port 8080

int main(){
    
    WSADATA ws;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&ws);

    int buffer = (1024)*8;

   // char incoming[buffer];
    
    sockaddr_in config;

    config.sin_family = AF_INET;
    config.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    config.sin_port = htons(port);
    
    SOCKET soc;

    soc = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);

    int err = connect(soc,(sockaddr*)&config,sizeof(config));

    if(err!=0){
        std::cout << "Could not connect" <<std::endl;
    }else{
        std::cout << "Connected Successfully" <<std::endl;
    }

    FILE *target;
    
    int stat;
    char fileByte[buffer]={0};
    
   while(1){
    
    fileByte[0]=0;
    
    stat = recv(soc,fileByte,buffer,0);
    
    fwrite(fileByte,buffer,1,target);
    
    fileByte[0]=0;
    
    if(stat<0){
        break;
    }
   
   }
   
   std::cout << strlen(fileByte) << std::endl;

    fclose(target);

    
    return 0;
    
}
```

Comment: I did not read the entire code, but I don't see you checking the return value of `fread`. fread returns 'the number of chunks actually read', which is exactly the number of bytes you need to pass to send, otherwise you'll always end up sending the entire buffer, which may still contain 'old bytes'. Not every file is exactly a multiple of 'buffer' bytes long, after all.

Comment: Are you actually using the returned size value?  I also didn't read the entire code, but that is the usual mistake I have come across, and that is not using the actual return codes/sizes that are presented.  Instead, the mistake is either sticking inappropriate nulls in the returned buffer, or using functions/classes that use a terminating null to determine when to "stop" on data that already has embedded nulls (like your erroneous `strlen` call), or just assuming "I asked for n bytes, so I will get back n bytes".

Comment: In addition to the above, there's no error checking on the `recv` function either, until _after_ writing data to the file.  What's more is you also don't check how many bytes were actually received.  You're just writing a full buffer length to the file.  I do wish you didn't use the identifier `buffer` to describe a _size_.

Comment: There are at least two obvious problems here: you assume in the server that `send` sends everything instead of checking the return code. You assume in the client that `recv` receives everything instead of checking the return code. Both assumptions are wrong.

Comment: Honestly, a debugger is the best tool for this job.

Comment: As a side note, while I truly appreciate you sharing 'enough code to reproduce the problem', what we're usually looking for is an [mre].

Comment: `std::cout << strlen(fileByte) << std::endl;` That should be:  --> `std::cout.write(fileByte, stat);` -- This is exactly what I was referring to in the comments about using functions that stop on the first null byte, instead of using the returned value from the `recv` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the same issue two times, namely 'number of bytes'.

Try this:

```
int32_t readBytes;
while((readBytes = fread(filebyte, 1, buffer, src)) > 0)
    send(acpt,filebyte, readBytes,0);
```

for the server side and, on the client side:

```
int stat;
while((stat = recv(soc,fileByte,buffer,0)) > 0)
    fwrite(fileByte,1, stat,target);
```

This code is 'off the top of my head', so you may need to adapt it accordingly.

To explain what's going on: `fread` will return the 'number of elements read' (see the man page for more details), which is 'less than buffer' for the last block of a file.

If you always send the whole buffer, this will result in a 'padded output', the last part being 'whatever was in the file at the position during the previous read', which leads to the problem you described.

Similarly, if you always write the whole buffer, the result file will be padded in the same way.

Edit:
As has been brought to my attention, your code has yet another flaw, namely that your client will continue to wait for more data, until the server closes the connection, which does not happen.

In order to do that, you need to call

```
shutdown(acpt, 2);
closesocket(acpt);
```

after the read/send block.

Alternatively, if you want to keep the connection open, you will need to add additional information to your protocol.

Comment: I got to know about my faults reading your answer and those code snippets helped me a lot to know what was possibly going wrong in my code, Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome, @CoderBittu. And welcome to StackOverflow. :)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers/comments-

The server code is not closing the TCP connection after sending the file is complete, so the client doesn't know when to terminate its reading loop at the end of the file.

The server should either

- send the file size before sending the file data. The client can then read the size first, and then stop the loop when the specified number of bytes have been received.
- send a fixed header before each buffer, containing the buffer size. Then it can send a 0-length buffer after the file is done. The client can then read each header and buffer until it reads the 0-length buffer's header.